# Trying to store strings returned by strsep gives seg fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function messtowords that takes a string as an input and saves the split words into an array of strings.

```
void messtowords(char* string,char** result){
    char* found;
    char* temp=strdup(string);
    char* del=" ";
    int i=0;
    char* in=temp;

    while(found!=NULL){
        found=strsep(&in,del);
        result[i]=found;
        i++;

    }

}

int main(void){
    char TC_norep[]="This is a test string";
    char* words[100];
    messtowords(TC_norep,words);
    printf("%s",words[0]);

}
```

But I get a segmentation fault on the line where I assign result[i]=found. But I defined words as an array of character pointers so shouldn't I be able to modify it's elements? What would be the correct way of storing the split up words into an array?

EDIT: I made the recommended changes but still:
[image]

Comment: `found` is uninitialized. How do you know the loop is entered?

Comment: PSA: Try not to create uninitialized variables. Get into the habit of giving them defaults, like in this case `char* found = NULL`.

Comment: Your `strdup` allocation here needs to be dealt with after. You should likely either avoid the `strdup` call and just return pointers to the original `char* string`. Additionally, you **must** ensure that `result` has enough entries, so you should likely take another argument with `result_size` given.

Comment: Another thing to note is this is often easier with either `strtok` if you can mangle the original string buffer, or a custom parser with its own allocations if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example that works here https://godbolt.org/z/n9Eh7WW67

I added includes, initialized all of the entries in the words array to `NULL` so it is possible to know how many words were stored, restructured the loop, and returned the duplicated string so it could be freed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* messtowords(char* string,char** result){
    char* found;
    char* temp=strdup(string);
    char* del=" ";
    int i=0;
    char* in=temp;

    while ((found = strsep(&in,del)) != NULL)
    {
        result[i]=found;
        i++;
    }

    return temp;
}

int main(void){
    char TC_norep[]="This is a test string";
    char* words[100] = {NULL};
    char* temp = messtowords(TC_norep,words);
    for (int i = 0; words[i] != NULL; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n",words[i]);
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I was using some definition of strsep that I found on another post which was causing issues. I forgot about string.h

Answer (score 4):

`found` is not initialized. `while(found!=NULL)` tests `found` before it is given a value. The code may act as though `found` is a null pointer and never enter the loop, so no assignment to `result[i]` is made.

Comment: Ok. I changed it to be char* found=malloc(10) which is big enough to store any of the words in my test string but I still get the same seg fault

Comment: No, not that. You don't need an allocation. You need to **initialize to `NULL`**. If you do what you're suggesting then you leak memory.

Comment: If `found` is initialized to `NULL` the loop never runs. `while ((found = strsep(&in,del)) != NULL) { ... }` is a better loop.

Comment: Please see my edit. This did not fix it

Comment: you should be adding #include<string.h> to use string functions.